# Установка водного знака на изображение

Tags: php

Как совместить наложение водяного знака и сохранение изображений, которые загрузил пользователь

```
 //$photo_ex == $_FILE[photo]
foreach ($photos_ex as $photo_ex) {

    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('http://localhost/picture/stamp.png');
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo_ex["tmp_name"]);

    // Установка полей для штампа и получение высоты/ширины штампа
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    // Копирование изображения штампа на фотографию с помощью смещения края
    // и ширины фотографии для расчета позиционирования штампа. 
    imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

   if(is_uploaded_file($photo_ex["tmp_name"])){
        move_uploaded_file($photo_ex["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photos/". '2.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list($name, $ext) = preg_split('/\./', $photo_ex['name']);

imagepng($im, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/photos/'.md5($name).".$ext");
```

как-то так

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($photos_ex as $photo_ex) {

  if(is_uploaded_file($photo_ex["tmp_name"])){
       $newName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photos/". $photo_ex["name"];
       move_uploaded_file($photo_ex["tmp_name"], $newName);
       $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('http://localhost/picture/stamp.png');
      $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($newName);

      .....
      .....

   }
}
```

т.е. грузите на сервер и потом уже накладываете. Ну конечно с проверками что это действительно изображение, а не шел какой.